# Ajax pagination $_GET parameters in Controller

Tags: ajax, yii, pagination

I am trying to understand how the Yii pagination for posts works in the Blog demo app and I see this request in the firebug console:

```
http://localhost/blog/index.php/post/index?ajax=yw0&Post_page=2
```

The function 'actionIndex' in the **PostController** does not seem to use the `$_GET` params. Where does the magic happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such things you should check the source.

The index function would have a `CActiveDataProvider` whose `fetchData` function does this work.

Basically a `CListView`, or a `CGridView` calls the [`getData` function of a data provider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDataProvider#getData-detail), which calls [`fetchData` (say of CActiveDataProvider)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider#fetchData-detail), which in turn calls [`CPagination`'s `applyLimit`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination#applyLimit-detail), which calls [`getOffset`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination#getOffset-detail), and this function calls [`getCurrentPage`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CPagination#getCurrentPage-detail):

```
if(isset($_GET[$this->pageVar])) // this is where the $_GET is used
```

Comment: 10x.. it was a long way till there:)